# How can I configure and print with an HP LaserJet 1000?

Tags: 10.04, printing, hp

Could anyone help me to configure printer? I tried googling but haven't found anything.

EDIT:
system->administration->printing there are no printers and cant add new one, add button is unclickable

at the beginning I didn't try to add printer and was installing those drivers, maybe I ruined something? I used this guide ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-112556.html by maulattu 3rd post..

Comment: @fossfreedom I plugged it in and what's then? When going to system->administration->printing there are no printers and cant add new one, no options available

Comment: ? You do have "Configure Printers" checked in Advanced-Settings of Users & Groups?? - logout - login and then you'll be able to "add" a printer i.e. click the add button on administration --> printing

Comment: @fossfreedom yes I had but at the beginning I didn't try to add printer and was installing those drivers, maybe I ruined something?  I used this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-112556.html by maulattu 3rd post..

Comment: @fossfreedom I don't know if I lost driver or not, but add button is inactive

Comment: you needed to simply reinstall the cups package to resolve this.  Installing hplip by the answer below also would have reinstalled cups.  Anyway - glad it is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading and the latest HP printer drivers.  I prefer this over using the ones that come with Ubuntu or Ubuntu's repository.

http://hplipopensource.com/